# PageObject "wait element" method don't work

Tags: ruby, cucumber, selenium-webdriver, page-object-gem

I'm working on test automation with cucumber, selenium-webdriver and page-object gem.
When I try to run simple test cucumber catch the following error:

```
  Scenario: Going to billing                # features/test.feature:10
    When I click 'Платные услуги'           # features/step_definitions/test_steps.rb:13
      Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Платные услуги"} (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError)
      [remote server] file:///tmp/webdriver-profile20130412-21410-z4p1ez/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:8405:in `FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_'
      [remote server] file:///tmp/webdriver-profile20130412-21410-z4p1ez/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:8414:in `FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElement'
      [remote server] file:///tmp/webdriver-profile20130412-21410-z4p1ez/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10421:in `DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h'
      [remote server] file:///tmp/webdriver-profile20130412-21410-z4p1ez/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10426:in `DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_'
      [remote server] file:///tmp/webdriver-profile20130412-21410-z4p1ez/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10366:in `DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/<'
      ./features/pages/job_main_page.rb:38:in `go_to_billing'
      ./features/step_definitions/test_steps.rb:14:in `/^I click 'Платные услуги'$/'
      features/test.feature:11:in `When I click 'Платные услуги''
```

Here is the cucumber feature:

```
Scenario: Going to billing
    When I click 'Платные услуги'
    Then I should see "Коммерческие услуги"
```

Step definition where test falls:

```
When(/^I go to billing$/) do
    @job_myroom_billing = @job_myroom.billing_element.when_visible.go_to_billing
end
```

And page object:

```
class BasePage
    include PageObject
    include RSpec::Matchers
end

class JobMyroom < BasePage 
    link :billing, link: 'Платные услуги'

    def go_to_billing
        billing
        JobMyroomBilling.new @browser
    end
end

class JobMyroomBilling < JobMyroom    
     #some code
end
```

Whats wrong? Driver don't wait the element's presence

Comment: Apprently you open a new browser, right ?

Comment: It never waits for the element to appear. The solution we used is: There is an element that is loaded last -> add an extra 'wait for the element' before the test code runs. There are special methods to wait for an element to appear.

Comment: e1che, yes I use "before do", "after do" methods in hooks.rb: "@browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox" and "@browser.close"

Comment: User, why it never waits the element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Sheg is giving some good advice here although I would tend to do it slightly different:

```
wait_until do
  billing_element.visible?
end
```

Another thing you can do that is very similar is to replace the code in your method with this:

```
def go_to_billing
  billing_element.when_present.click
  JobMyroomBilling.new @browser
end
```

In this case we are waiting until the link is present and when it is the `when_present` method returns the element and we simply click on it.

Another thing I might suggest is using watir-webdriver as the driver instead of selenium-webdriver.  watir-webdriver is built on top of selenium-webdriver but seems the have far better handling of waiting for items to actually be loaded on the DOM.  If your link is being added dynamically using Ajax then you will have to write some code to wait until it is there before actually interacting with it.  The only thing you will have to do to use the other gem is change the code in your `Before` block to this:

```
Before do
  @browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
end
```

Another pointer I would give you is to not have one page object return an instance of the next page object.  I am eating my own words here because a few years ago this is how I did it but I have found over time that this is a brittle approach.  Instead, I would use the `PageObject::PageFactory` to manage the creation of the correct pages and when you have a step that is a generic step you can simply use the `@current_page` instance variable.

The last pointer I will give you is to remove the assertions from your page object.  I would have the page object simply provide the abstraction and perform all verification in the step definitions.  This is a much cleaner separation of concerns and will make maintaining your tests easier over time.

Comment: Thanks! 'when_present' and 'click' methods helps me. PageObject::PageFactory - I just leverage that thing and my steps definitions looks much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

either you can use sleep methode from java with try catch. or implicitwait for selenium webdriver.
Webdriver never wait for the element to be displayed... basically you need the delay.

Answer (score 0):

The page object when_visible method is meant to wait for Ajax events to finish loading, as mentioned here https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/wiki/Ajax-Calls.

If webdriver is trying to click on the link element before it is completely rendered, and is not Ajax related, consider waiting until the element is displayed with webdriver first. For example:

```
wait.until { driver.find_element(:link_text => "Платные услуги").displayed? }
@job_myroom.go_to_billing
```

You could (highly recommended) implicitly do this with all elements by invoking the following right after you instantiate your webdriver:

```
driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 3
```

In addition, in many situations, I have found that locating links by href performs a lot better than link_text. Perhaps these could solve your element timing issues.